# Pass generic method omitting its parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression-trees

Is there a way to pass a method name in a generic manner, without passing its parameters, so it can be invoked by the method, with passed arguments?

Consider this example:

```
public class Client
{
  public string Convert(int value)
  {
    return value.ToString();
  }
}

public class Wrapper<TClient>
{
  TClient Client;

  public TResult Invoke<TArg, TResult>(Func<TClient, TArg, TResult> action, TArg arg)
  {
    return action(Client, arg);
  }
}
```

I want to be able to pass to the wrapper the method of `TClient` I want to invoke, and pass the actual arguments along, all generically:

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper<Client>();
wrapper.Invoke(c => c.Convert, 5);
```

Is there any possible way to achieve that, without hard coding the method name, or losing its genericness (i.e. by using `Delegate`)?

Notes:

The `Client` is an external sealed class that exposes a gazillion methods each of many parameters. I want wrap its behavior and I don't mind writing all the necessary code in the wrapper, but the usage of the wrapper should be as clean as possible.

**Update**
I want to avoid the need to specify the parameters. The whole idea is having them inferred from the specified action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close to getting your code to run. There are two options.

First, you can try this:

```
public class Wrapper<TClient>
{
    public TResult Invoke<TArg, TResult>(Func<TArg, TResult> action, TArg arg)
    {
        return action(arg);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
var wrapper = new Wrapper<Client>();    
wrapper.Invoke(wrapper.client.Convert, 5);
```

Or, alternatively, you can do this:

```
public class Wrapper<TClient>
{
    public Wrapper(TClient client)
    {
        this.Client = client;
    }

    private TClient Client;

    public TResult Invoke<TArg, TResult>(Func<TClient, TArg, TResult> action, TArg arg)
    {
        if (operation.Target != Client)
          throw new ArgumentException(nameof(operation));

        return action(this.Client, arg);
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var client = new Client();
var wrapper = new Wrapper<Client>(client);

wrapper.Invoke((c, a) => c.Convert(a), 5);
```

But, from your description of your problem, I don't see how either of these help and I don't see how to implement what you're asking. Perhaps you need to provide more detail as to what the underlying need you're trying to solve?

Comment: The problem with the first snippet is that you're instantiating the `Client`, instead of using the one stored in `Wrapper`.

Comment: I wish there would be a mix of the two, so I don't 1) have to give a reference to the client for the user, 2) so I don't have to name all params (there will be lots of them!). I guess I'll just go for your first solution, cuz naming the parameters frightens me much more than exposing the client.

Comment: I've updated your code, with the way I'm gonna do it, the client will anyway be contained.

Answer (score 2):

You want the expression being passed to `Invoke` to return a `Func` that accepts `TArg`. In code:

```
public class Wrapper<TClient>
{
    TClient Client;

    public TResult Invoke<TArg, TResult>(Func<TClient, Func<TArg, TResult>> action, TArg arg)
    {
        return action(Client)(arg);
    }
}
```

You can then invoke it like so:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wrapper = new Wrapper<Client>();
        string result = wrapper.Invoke<int, string>(c => c.Convert, 5);
    }
}
```

---

Since you don't like the approach of having to explicitly specify type arguments, you can use a slightly different API (which comes with its own annoyances):

```
public class Wrapper<TClient>
{
    TClient Client;

    public void Invoke<TArg, TResult>(Func<TClient, Func<TArg, TResult>> action, TArg arg, out TResult result)
    {
        return action(Client)(arg);
    }
}
```

You can call this like so, with the return type inferred from the `out` parameter:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wrapper = new Wrapper<Client>();
        string result;
        wrapper.Invoke(c => c.Convert, 5, out result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid specifying types. The client exposes a zillion methods each of a various number of parameters. My goal is to avoid the need to specify all the parameter types again and make the usage of the wrapper as smooth as possible.

Comment: @Shimmy Unfortunately it isn't possible to implicitly resolve the method group to a `Func` without specifying the types explicitly, since the compiler is cautious about method overloading.

Comment: Any workaround? Problem is once you have to specify one type argument, you have to specify all of them, am I right?

Comment: I don't mind omitting the `TResult` does it make the situation any better?

Comment: @Shimmy That works, if you don't mind passing a wrapping lambda like so: `c => arg => c.Convert(arg)`.

Comment: @Shimmy See the alternative I've added.

Comment: @Shimmy Does that work? If you don't like the `out` approach I can also add code to show how the case where `TResult` is removed works.